# how to extract the table from database and open it into .pdf file using PHP?

Tags: php, database, pdf

I am trying to extract the table from database and trying to open it in `.pdf`-file, but i am facing problem in opening to it in `.pdf`-file , when i am trying it prompt a message which is given below,

> "Acrobat could not open "Report.pdf" because it is either not a
>   supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example,
>   it was sent as an eamil attachment and wasnt correctly decoded).
>
> To create an adobe PDF document,go to the source application. then
>   print the document to Adobe PDF."

Comment: Do you mean "trying to create a PDF-file from a database"? In this case, what are you using to create the PDF and what's your code. If not, please be more specific on what you want to do.

Comment: yeah i am trying to create a PDF-file from a database, i am using PHP

Comment: @Aamir well, what library are you using to create the PDF file?

Comment: @ Pekka, dude i am not using any library

Comment: So, how are you doing it then? Post your code.

Comment: He's not doing any SQL > PDF, he's just trying to open a dump of sql with PDF reader, which of course - doesn't work. Sticking .pdf file extension to a file doesn't make it readable by PDF. Downvoted for lack of effort, you could have googled how to convert something to PDF instead of asking SO to solve all your development problems. Asking for help the instant you get stuck isn't learning.

Comment: This can go straight into the FAQ as how not to ask a question.

Comment: @N.B, yeah you right this what i am asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generating a pdf file in php can be difficult. http://www.fpdf.org/ seems to be recommended, but i have never used it. Otherwise, please post some code as a lot of the PHP pdf functions are depreciated http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdf.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use fpdf to create pdf files..

See http://www.fpdf.org/

See this for simple tutorial on dpdf  http://www.elated.com/articles/create-nice-looking-pdfs-php-fpdf/